# Как создать динамические модели в Django?

Tags: django

Имею я два приложения. Как написать что бы при добавлении записи автоматически создавался объект модели в котором могу добавлять записи?
К примеру у меня есть:

```
#Приложение по играм
class ListGames(models.Model):
     name_game = models.Charfield(max_lenght=20)
```

Так же у меня есть отдельное приложение которое будет хранить информацию о играх в которой следующая модель:

```
#Приложение о играх
class InfoGames(models.Model):
     name_info_for_games = models.CharField(max_lenght=20)
     info_games = models.TextField(max_lenght=156)
```

Как сделать что бы при добавлении названия игр в первом приложении, создавалось автоматически объект в другом приложении в котором могу добавлять сколько угодно записей об этой игре?

Comment: Думаю, с помощью сигналов можно.

Comment: А по подробней если не трудно можно? Но если нет, поищу, спасибо что хоть в какое русло идти подсказали

Comment: Вообще тут OneToOneField напрашивается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно реализовать при помощи сигнала `post_save`.

***Пример:***

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=ListGames)
def func(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        InfoGames.objects.create(name_info_for_games='some', info_games='some')
```

Функция `func` будет вызываться каждый раз при сохранении модели `ListGames` и если модель была только что создана, создаст экземпляр `InfoGames`.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, теперь понял, спасибо за ответ